# How to load part of html page in django?

Tags: python, html, django

Before I used to load just part of page in django. Usually it used to be a text that I did not want change often, but I forgot how to do it, now I cannot find it.

I have two html docs, in one I want to load other, can you tell me where I made a mistake?

Text to load text_story.html

```
<p>Some text!</p>
```

Page where is loaded text about.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% load "parts/text_story.html" %}

{% block content %}


{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`{% include %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

{% include "parts/text_story.html" %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works, but it needs to be inside of {% block content %}.

Comment: @project.py you're correct, I missed that part. Fixed.